# Angular template for a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I'm ashamed to ask such an elementary question but I tried to DRY up this template a couple ways and couldn't come up with anything I was satisfied with. Can you help?

```
  %ul.dropdown-menu(aria-labelledby="single-button" role="menu" uib-dropdown-menu)
    %li(role="menuitem")
      %a(href="/legal-forms/admin/document_templates/{{ documentTemplate.id }}/edit") Edit
    %li(role="menuitem")
      %a(href="/legal-forms/admin/document_templates/{{ documentTemplate.id }}/open_in_wizard") Create Document
    %li(role="menuitem")
      %a(href="/legal-forms/admin/document_templates/{{ documentTemplate.id }}/preview" document-template-preview="true" id="documentTemplate.id") Preview
    %li(role="menuitem" ng-hide="documentTemplate.parent_id")
      %a(href=true ng-click="copy(documentTemplate)") Copy
    %li(role="menuitem")
      %a(href=true ng-click="delete(documentTemplate)") Delete
```

Comment: What templating language/framework is it written in/with?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is solid code. All I can think of is a repeat pointing to an array in the controller. I do this on some of our web apps that have high-freq of changes to menu items.

I don't know if this would really be a good refactor otherwise as it just abstracts away more of the template but it definitely DRY's it up.

BTW I'm not familiar with that templating lib so I apologize if there are any problems with the syntax.

template

```
 %ul.dropdown-menu(aria-labelledby="single-button" role="menu" uib-dropdown-menu)
        %li(role="menuitem" ng-repeat="item in doc_dropdown")
          %a(
             href={{ ( item.is_path ) ? item.pathLocation : true }} 
             ng-click={{ item.clickTrigger }}
             ng-hide={{ ( item.can_hide ) ? "documentTemplate.parent_id" : "" }}
            ) 
                {{item.text}}
```

somewhere in the controller

```
doc_dropdown = [
    {
        is_path: true,
        pathLocation: "/legal-forms/admin/document_templates/{{ documentTemplate.id }}/edit", 
        text: "Edit", 
        click_trigger: null,
        can_hide: false 
    },{
        is_path: true,
        pathLocation: "/legal-forms/admin/document_templates/{{ documentTemplate.id }}/open_in_wizard", 
        text: "Create Document", 
        click_trigger: null,
        can_hide: false 
    },{
        is_path: true,
        pathLocation: "/legal-forms/admin/document_templates/{{ documentTemplate.id }}/preview", 
        text: "Preview", 
        click_trigger: null,
        can_hide: false 
    },{
        is_path: false,
        pathLocation: null, 
        text: "Copy", 
        click_trigger: "copy(documentTemplate)",
        can_hide: true  
    },{
        is_path: false,
        pathLocation: null, 
        text: "Delete", 
        click_trigger: "delete(documentTemplate)",
        can_hide: false 
    },
];
```